# Crud Mongodb With ASP.NET error 400 bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am doing a crud operation in asp.net, I get a json that contains 12 attributes. They are of an array type. When I send a POST back it returns an error 400 (Bad Request). Debugging the code it only goes until the class independence injection and already returns an error.

Searching I found that you might be json that I am sending and the MODEL that method of Controller receive

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Guid), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)]

public async Task<IActionResult> Add(Employee address)
{

}
```

---

```
public class Employee
    {
        [BsonId]
        public Guid ownerId { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("personalData")]
        public PersonalData personalData { get; set;}
        [BsonElement("address")]
        public Address address { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("emails")]
        public Emails emails { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("syndicate")]
        public Syndicate syndicate { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("dependents")]
        public Dependents dependents { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("phone")]
        public Phone phone { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("bank")]
        public Bank bank { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("attributes")]
        public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("benefits")]
        public Benefits benefits { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("transport")]
        public Transport transport { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("attachments")]
        public Attachments attachments {get; set; }
        [BsonElement("documents")]
        public Documents documents { get; set; }

    }
```

I have some doubts, the PersonalData, Address model must have

> [BsonElement ("")]

How do I get a json with an array to map to these guys?
Any material I can look at?